# Making a rich tooltip with CSS3 Transitions only (or at least, mostly)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm not a pro in CSS but I'm trying to learn.

I have this little sandbox going on:
[image]

It's basically a bunch of icons with some extra detail that is displayed once you hover over the icon.

I've been playing around with CSS trying to make this work but I get erratic behaviour so far. [Code is here](http://jsbin.com/arocaj/10/edit)

I wonder if I could somehow immitate a rich tooltip so it opens up when the icon is hovered over, and without changing the position of the other icons.

Any creative idea, including a change in basic design, will be gladly accepted.

My goal is to achieve this using CSS3 Transitions so minimal to no JavaScript is ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use hint.css, its a pure css tooltip

http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need tutorial to view [Create CSS3 Tooltip](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php) and the main code is

```
<a title="Create Simple Tooltip Using CSS3" class="tooltip">Some Sample CSS3 Tooltip</a>

.tooltip
{
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after
{
 background: #333;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 border-radius: 5px;
 bottom: 26px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(title);
 left: 20%;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 98;
 width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before
{
 border: solid;
 border-color: #333 transparent;
 border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
 bottom: 20px;
 content: "";
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
}
```